# display none by default and visible on mouseover

Tags: css, hover, hide, opacity

This is the CSS for the header DIV:

```
#header { 
  display: block;
  float: left;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 170px;
  height: auto; 
  background-color: #030309; 
  background-color: #191718; 
  position:fixed; 
  margin-top: -210px; 
  z-index: 999999; 
  opacity:.76;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
}
```

and this is for the hover state:

```
#header:hover { 
  display:block; 
  opacity:1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;   
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

What I want to make it so the header is hidden by default and appears when it's hovered. I've tried to add `display: none` on `#header` and `display:block;` on `#header:hover` but it's not working. 
I've tried also with `opacity:0;` on `#header` and `opacity:1;` on `#header:hover` but it's not ok because the content beneath the header remains fixed  and it's not visible from top of the page.

Some suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have a `margin-top:-210px` that is causing the header to be not visible but you're never moving it down to `0` on hover. Take that out. Then you can just set the `opacity` to 0 normally and 1 on hover and it'll fade it in on hover.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QNapD/2/)

Alternatively, if you want it to slide down, change the transition from just `opacity` to `all` and set a `top:0` in the `:hover` state. You also need to set a height that is greater than the negative top margin so part of the element will be visible so the user can hover over it. I set it to `220px`.

**Relevant changes in CSS:**

```
#header {
    top:-210px;
    height: 220px;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#header:hover {
    opacity:1;
    top:0px;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
}​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QNapD/1/)

Comment: I've tried with your code but I have the same problem, it remains empty space between the header and content. you can check [here](http://whiteandgold.ro/ipp/)

Answer (score 5):

"`display: none;`" means the element is removed from the document flow, so it's impossible to have a :hover state because there's nothing to hover-over.

Are you thinking of `visibility: hidden;` (effectively the same as `opacity: 0;`) instead?

Try adding `outline:` to your CSS to help you see the box in the document viewport so you know you're hovering over it for sure.

Comment: I've tried with visibility:hidden; but it remains that empty space and I don't want this, you can check [here](http://whiteandgold.ro/ipp/)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, doesn't make sense - your header is not visible at first, so it can't be hovered. That's why it won't show up.

What you can do is:

- Hide the block initially, like you did.
- Wrap the `#header` element with another element. Lets say you are tagging it with the id `#header-container`.
- Use the CSS: `#header-container:hover #header { display: block; }`

This will allow you to provide an element for the client to `hover` on in order to show the `#header`, while initially hiding it.